# Recieving JSON but unable to write onto page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I was able to get JSON data from a php file using ajax. I console.logged it and the data is there in JSON format. However, when I try to reference a specific parameter, it doesn't come out, instead saying,

```
    "VM160:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 79
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (debate.php:202)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2) ".
```

As far as the PHP goes, I queried the database and created a $data array, then encoded it:

```
$data['title'] = $row['title'];
$data['first'] = $row['first_option'];
$data['second'] = $row['second_option'];
$data['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
$data['uid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

I already tried using JSON.parse before referencing the variable that had the JSON data.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `console.log`?

Comment: Did you manually create that json...or use `json_encode()` to create it? Show us how it gets sent from php.

Comment: @charlietfl I used json_encode. I queried the database and made an array:  $data['title'] = $row['title'];
 $data['first'] = $row['first_option'];
 $data['second'] = $row['second_option'];
 $data['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
 $data['uid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
 echo json_encode($data);

Comment: ok and that `echo json_encode($data)` is outside of any loop? Can only echo json once and once only

Comment: @charlietfl No it's inside of a while loop ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)).

Comment: @charlietfl How would I loop through all of the data I need if it were outside?

Comment: So there is a loop?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah it's inside of a while loop. do you want me to paste the full query

Comment: No...query is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a loop you need an outer array that you add to each iteration then send that outer array when loop completes.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
   $data['title'] = $row['title'];
   $data['first'] = $row['first_option'];
   $data['second'] = $row['second_option'];
   $data['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
   $data['uid'] = $row['uidUsers']; 
   $results[] = $data;    
}

// only one echo allowed for json request
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: I did this and it's being recieved by the browser, but when I specify a parameter, it comes out as "undefined" (when I console.log "data", all the JSON is visible, but when I console.log "data.title", it comes out as undefined).

Comment: Right because you need to loop through the javascript array and access each object... `data.forEach(function(item) {console.log(item.title)})`

Comment: Or `console.log(data[0].title)` to just get first one

Comment: Should I console.log(data[0].title) inside the success function? Because it's still returning undefined, not sure if I'm missing a more basic component or something.

Comment: Nvm I just figured it out. I was missing the "dataType: json" parameter. Thanks man